# Spring-Kafka RetryableTopic causes RecordTooLargeException

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka RetryableTopic for non-blocking retries with a fixed BackOff and a single retry topic (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#single-topic-fixed-delay-retries)

I noticed that I get `RecordTooLargeException` when retry-attempt is relatively high, and while checking the message I see that it contains the Kafka headers for all previous attempts, and some headers like `kafka_exception-stacktrace` they are quite heavy.

Why does it try to publish the retry message with the headers of the previous retries?
I can not find any configuration for that.
Can these headers somehow be manipulated to cut them before publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point; I opened an issue.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1994

I'll see if I can come up with a work-around until this is implemented.

**EDIT**

```java
public class HeaderStrippingInterceptor<K, V> implements ProducerInterceptor<K, V> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<K, V> onSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> record) {
        Header header = record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE);
        if (header != null) {
            record.headers().remove(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE);
            record.headers().add(header);
        }
        return record;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAcknowledgement(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

Then add its class name to the producer configs; for example, with Spring Boot:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      properties:
        "[interceptor.classes]": com.example.demo.HeaderStrippingInterceptor
```

Comment: I added a work around; see the edit.